# Backup an LG watch urbane

Tags: backup, android-wear

I'm now trying to backup my Android wear. I got the drivers from the official LG website, but nothing appears when I plug it in. Driver manager reports no errors, so i guess it didnt detect the watch. Usb 2.0. Can someone help me on what to do? Thanks.
Technical setup: Usb 2.0 (my connection) Windows 10, using charging dock.

Comment: Please add more details about the exact behavior you're seeing and what you are doing.  I assume you're on Windows -- what version?  How are you connecting the device (USB2 / USB3)?  Was the device detected (& drivers installed) the first time you plugged it in?  What does the Device Manager show as the entry for this device -- is there an error?

Comment: @MatthewRead just edited-reopen my question.

Comment: Edity, try using the LG BRIDGE. Here ya go: http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000026-1438110404543-preinstall-apps

Comment: I did use the LG BRIDGE